# Reading logical operators expression for truth table C++

Tags: c++, boolean, operators, parentheses, truthtable

I am trying to write a code that will take an expression that is formatted similar to

```
(((p∨q)∧((q→r)⊕(p∧r)))↔(r∧q))→(p∨r)
```

and it needs to print out the truth table for it which looks something like

```
p q r  (p V q)   (q→r) etc... until it gets to (((p∨q)∧((q→r)⊕(p∧r)))↔(r∧q))→(p∨r)
t t t     t         t    
t t f     t         f
t f t     t         t
t f f     t         t
f t t     t         t
f t f     t         f
f f t     f         t
f f f     f         t
```

i devised a way to deal with the XOR and implies operators, but I realized that it only works when the operators are inside the inner parentheses, not when the operators are between two sets of parentheses...

I have been working on this for way too many hours, can someone give me insight on what I can use instead?

Now that I think about it more, could I just make try to read in the first (), then the second () and so forth as individual variables, convert them to booleans the computer will understand, and then inject those back into the proper format in the right order?

The source code I am working on right now is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    bool p[8] = { true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false };         // Declare the init T/F values
    bool q[8] = { true, true, false, false, true, true, false, false };
    bool r[8] = { true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false };

    std::string expression;                                     
    std::cout << "Enter expression (using ^ for AND, V for OR, X for XOR, and I for Implies (-->): \n";
    std::getline(std::cin, expression);


    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> exprVector;
    for (std::string::iterator it = expression.begin; it != expression.end(); it++)
    {
        if (expression.at(i) == 'p')
        {
            exprVector[i] = "p[i]";
        }
        else if (expression.at(i) == 'q')
        {
            exprVector[i] = "q[i]";
        }
        else if (expression.at(i) == 'r')
        {
            exprVector[i] = "r[i]";
        }

        else if (expression.at(i) == '(')
        {
            exprVector[i] = "(";
        }
        else if (expression.at(i) == ')')
        {
            exprVector[i] = ") ";
        }
        else if (expression.at(i) == '^')
        {
            exprVector[i] = "&&";
        }
        else if (expression.at(i) == 'V')
        {
            exprVector[i] = "||";
        }
        else if (expression.at(i) == 'X')
        {
            char temp1;
            char temp2;
            i--;
            if (exprVector[i] == "p[i]")                                        // (p XOR q)
            {
                i++;
                i++;
                if (exprVector[i] == "q[i]")
                {

                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((p[i] || q[i]) && ((p[i] && q[i]) == false))";

                }
                else if (exprVector[i] == "r")                                  // (p XOR r)
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((p[i] || r[i]) && ((p[i] && r[i]) == false))";
                }
            }
            else if (exprVector[i] == "q")                                      // (q XOR p)
            {
                i++;
                i++;
                if (exprVector[i] == "p")
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((q[i] || p[i]) && ((q[i] && p[i]) == false))";

                }
                else if (exprVector[i] == "r")                                  // (q XOR r)
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((q[i] || r[i]) && ((q[i] && r[i]) == false))";
                }
            }
            else if (exprVector[i] == "r")                                      
            {
                i++;
                i++;
                if (exprVector[i] == "p")                                       // (r XOR p)
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((r[i] || p[i]) && ((r[i] && p[i]) == false)";
                }
                if (exprVector[i] == "q")                                       // (r XOR q)
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((r[i] || q[i]) && ((r[i] && q[i]) == false)";
                }
            }


        }
        else if (expression.at(i) == 'I')
        {
            if (exprVector[i] == "p[i]")                                        // (p ---> q)
            {
                i++;
                i++;
                if (exprVector[i] == "q[i]")
                {

                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((p[i] == true) || (q[i] == false)";

                }
                else if (exprVector[i] == "r")                                  // (p ---> r)
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((p[i] == true) || (r[i] == false)";
                }
            }
            else if (exprVector[i] == "q")                                      // (q ---> p)
            {
                i++;
                i++;
                if (exprVector[i] == "p")
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((q[i] == true) || (p[i] == false))";

                }
                else if (exprVector[i] == "r")                                  // (q ---> r)
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((q[i] == true) || (r[i] == false))";
                }
            }
            else if (exprVector[i] == "r")
            {
                i++;
                i++;
                if (exprVector[i] == "p")                                       // (r ---> p)
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((r[i] == true) || (p[i] == false))";
                }
                if (exprVector[i] == "q")                                       // (r ---> q)
                {
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                    i--;
                    //clear vector[i] from exprVector

                    exprVector[i] = "((r[i] == true) || (q[i] == false))";
                }

        }
        else if (expression.at(i) == '!')
        {
            i++
            if (exprVector[i] == "p")
            {
                //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                i--;
                //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                exprVector[i] == "(p[i] == false)"
            }
            if (exprVector[i] == "q")
            {
                //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                i--;
                //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                exprVector[i] == "(p[i] == false)"
            }
            if (exprVector[i] == "r")
            {
                //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                i--;
                //clear vector[i] from exprVector
                exprVector[i] == "(p[i] == false)"
            }

        }
        else if (expression.at(i) == ' ')
        {
        }

        i++;
        j++;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered something like an data structure that gives you a tree, allowing you to call print/eval at each node. Each node is either one of your variables, or an operator with child nodes.

Comment: I wanted to do that first, but I'm not sure how to deal with the parentheses..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a recursive descent parser?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Of possibly some other sort of parsing implementation.  Then you can generate a tree which represents the expression and next you can evaluate the tree for all the possible inputs.

Comment: Will this work if you put the input in any order? or would that only work if it had the same format (((  ∨  )∧((  →  )⊕(  ∧  )))↔(  ∧  ))→(  ∨  )

Comment: It's a general approach to taking in any sort of expressions so that they can be represented and evaluated programmatically.

Comment: Just trying to understand it better.. but it seems like its a little complex when we didn't do anything like that in my pre-req C++ classes, and my current class is Discrete Math